# uploading file with libcurl

Tags: c++, libcurl

Take a look at the following code

```
static size_t reader(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t retcode = fread(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    cout << "*** We read " << retcode << " bytes from file" << endl;
    return retcode;
}

void upload() { //upload() is called from ouside
    FILE *pFile;
    pFile = fopen("map.txt" , "r");

    struct stat file_info;
    stat("map.txt", &file_info);
    size_t size = (size_t)file_info.st_size;
    uploadFile(pFile, size);
}

bool uploadFile(void* data, size_t datasize) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        char *post_params = ...;
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, post_params);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (long) strlen(post_params));
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, reader);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t) datasize);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return true;
}
```

When the code is executed, the following is outputed

```
*** We read 490 bytes from file
*** We read 0 bytes from file
```

after that the app does nothing (even not exiting).

Can someone point out at what's wrong here?

Will be grateful for any help!!!

Comment: Can you check the return value from `stat()` to ensure it is succeeding and the `file_info.st_size` is correct.

Comment: Reason I asked this is due to `datasize` being specified as the size of the data and this quote from man page for [curl_easy_setopt](http://www.squarebox.co.uk/cgi-squarebox/manServer/curl_easy_setopt.3): "If you stop the current transfer by returning 0 "pre-maturely" (i.e before the server expected it, like when you’ve told you will upload N bytes and you upload less than N bytes), you may experience that the server "hangs" waiting for the rest of the data that won’t come."

Comment: @hmjd,`cout << size` outputs `102583`, and it's correct filesize.

Comment: @hmjd, anyway `size` is greater then `490` :)

Comment: Ok. Would suggest printing values of the arguments passed to the `reader()` function and the values of the arguments passed to the `uploadFile()` function. Only 490 bytes of the file are being read, significantly less than its actual size. Also print `ferror(stream)` and `feof(stream)` in `reader()` after the `fread()`.

Comment: The CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS and POSTFIELDSIZE shouldn't be there. And why do you typecast the file size to a size_t? On a 32bit arch that supports large file sizes that's not a good idea.

Comment: @DanielStenberg,I'm sure that 32 bits is more then enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's some serious confusions shown in this code. Let me try to explain:

[CURLOPT_UPLOAD](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_UPLOAD.html) - this will ask libcurl to PUT the file when the protocol of choice is HTTP

[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE.html) - tells libcurl to POST the data that is provided in the additional argument (which has the size set with [CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE.html))

[CURLOPT_READFUNCTION](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_READFUNCTION.html) - provides libcurl an alternative way to get data than CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to allow a POST that reads the data from a file. When using CURLOPT_UPLOAD this is the only way to provide data.

So in the end the questions left for you are:

- Do you want PUT or POST?
- Do you want to provide the data as a string or do you want it provided with a callback?